# Google App Engine: Preferred/idiomatic way to "refresh" a model from the datastore?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I have observed the following: (`Odp` is a model)

```
o = Odp.get(odpKey)
o.foo = 0
foo()
assert o.foo == 1 # fails

def foo():
    o = Odp.get(odpKey)
    o.foo += 1
    o.put()
```

It looks like the first copy of `o` isn't refreshed when it's underlying datastore representation is updated. So, what is the preferred way to refresh it?

I was thinking something like:

```
o = Odp.get(odpKey)
o.foo = 0
foo()
o = Odp.get(o.key())
assert o.foo == 1 # win
```

Or is there a better way?

Answer (score 4):

> t looks like the first copy of o isn't
>   refreshed when it's underlying
>   datastore representation is updated.

Correct: there are two completely independent objects in memory during the execution of function `foo` -- both happen to be bound to barenames equal to `o`, in different scopes, but that's an irrelevant detail (just further confusing things;-).

```
o = Odp.get(odpKey)
o.foo = 0
foo()
o = Odp.get(o.key())
assert o.foo == 1 # win
```

"win" only the first time -- because the `o.foo = 0` only affects a copy that's never put to the DB, and then `o` is rebound to a *third* copy just gotten from the DB, then `o.foo` will be `1` the *first* time (if the `foo` attribute defaults to `0`) but not on subsequent attempts as it keeps increasing by one every time.  You need an `o.put()` *before* the call to `foo()` to make the `o.foo = 0` assignment have any meaning or sense whatsoever.

A better idea is to have the `foo` function accept an optional argument (the object in question) and have it get a fresh copy only if it *didn't* receive that argument; and then in any case *return* the object it's working on.  IOW, you'd have:

```
o = Odp.get(odpKey)
o.foo = 0
o = foo(o)
assert o.foo == 1  # always OK

def foo(o=None):
  if o is None:
    o = Odp.get(odpKey)
  o.foo += 1
  return o
```

You might add an `o.put()` somewhere, but normally it's better to save only when a set of related changes have all been applied to the in-memory copy.  Doing essentially all the work on a single in-memory copy saves a lot of roundtrips to the DB and thereby speeds your app up by **a lot**.